# Matching with a regular expression in a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to do something which I am not sure is possible or not.

So here it is, I have one data set in my PostgreSQL table:

```
select * from company;

 id |     name         | age | 
----+------------------+-----+-
  2 | Spine_[1-9]_Leaf |  12 |
```

So basically I am storing a regular expression in `name` in the database.
It means if we pass in the query any value like `Spine_1_Leaf` ... `Spine_9_Leaf`, it should return the record:

```
  2 | Spine_[1-9]_Leaf |  12 |
```

because name string matches `name` (regex from the db). Please do let me know how can we make it possible. I am trying things like:

```
select * from company where name ~ 'Spine_1_Leaf'
```

Which is not working (and it should not be also).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the search string and term the wrong way round:

```
select * from company where 'Spine_1_Leaf' ~ name
```

is what you're after.

Comment: The purpose I can see for the context of the question is to store some patterns in the database and then query individual values.  So I would expect that the actual query would be `select * from company where ? ~ name` with ? filled with a user input...

Comment: Thanks beny it works I would like to know will it work for complex regex also or you will suggest some other approach

Comment: According to the Postgres docs, it'll work for any POSIX regexes: see here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-SYNTAX-DETAILS